# FindFaces on Raspbery Pi

Tags: programming

I think this is an standard question but I did'nt find any new answer since years. I try to use FindFaces on raspeberry pi. This function leads to an error message : opencv not available for raspberry pi. However chekcing on the net Open CV is now available on Debien. Is there any plan to implmeent the FindFaces function on raspberry pi, please ? If not in plans could you also tell us ?

Thanks a lot.
Fred

Comment: Remember that this is not a Wolfram support forum. You are speaking to a group of users like you, not to Wolfram developers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it cannot be answered by the community. It should be addressed directly to Wolfram Research.